# How to Write mock of method using with to send params

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby, rspec-rails

Hi I want to know how can I write rspec for the following

```
def find_user(content)
  user = User.find(content.to_i) || 
  User.find(email: content) rescue 
 nil
end
```

I tried writing

```
It "user with user name" do
  expect(User).to receive(:find).with(email: "test@a.com").and_return(user)
End
```

But I am gettig error saying

```
Argument Error
Block not Passed
```

Can someone please tell what am i missing

Comment: Can I please have the screenshot of your code and the console where the spec executed and end up with error.

Comment: Please don't spam the community with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815265/how-to-mock-the-method-with-specific-parameter

Answer (score -1):

I may look first at your code here.

```
def find_user(content)
  user = User.find(content.to_i) || 
  User.find(email: content) rescue 
 nil
end
```

What is content? I looks like you're expecting either a user_id or an email address.

Doing this from the console:

```
irb(main):080:0> User.find("email@email.com".to_i)
=> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=0)
```

So it seems as if having a generic `find_user` method may be contributing to some of the test writing confusion.

Many times, overly complex tests point to overly complex code.

Perhaps you need one method

`find_user_by_email(email)`

and another
`find_user_by_id(id)`

Also, refer to https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

It will automatically return `nil` if nothing is found.

Start there,  And then like the other commenters, then post your class, and the spec and we can go from there.

Comment: I think you've completely missed the point, please see the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67815265/how-to-mock-the-method-with-specific-parameter